# Check if variable is string or not in swift

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift

I want to get this : if texfield isnt empty, and it isnt string, show ... and if it is show this...

I found a way how to check if it isnt empty, but I can't think of how to check if it string or not.

```
    if input != nil {

        var resultOutput = input! * 7

        result.text = "Your cat's age is \(resultOutput)"

    } else {

        result.text = "Please enter your cats age"

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is to make sure that what your user enters is only a number and not a string.

So you can go ahead and do something like this.

```
    var age:Int? = textField.text.toInt()
    if(age != nil)
    {
        println("age is \(age!*7)")
    }
    else
    {
        println("enter correct age")
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can find this code, check it

```
var str = self.textField.text

var value =  str.toInt()
```

if "value" is nil, you can understand value is a string or empty,,

Answer (score 0):

This is where Swift's "if let" can come into play.

```
if let age = textField.text.toInt()
{
  result.text = "Your cat's age is \(age * 7)"
}
else
{
  result.text = "Please enter your cats age"
}
```